# Reading a string (from a file) in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have written a lexer and a parser in Prolog. It unifies a string with its AST. This is part for a compiler/interpreter project I am working on. Naturally, I now want to read the string from a file to parse it. However, the predicates I have found for this is **read**, and it only reads Prolog atoms and predicates, like files with

```
hello.
```

I have been twiddling with the **double_quotes** settings, but with no success.

I want to be able to read a file with something like this

```
let id = \x.x in id (S (S Z))
```

and then send this string to the parsing predicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`read_line_to_codes/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_line_to_codes%2F2) or [`read_line_to_codes/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_line_to_codes%2F3). An example program which reads individual lines from [stdin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) and prints them to [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) is the following:

```
read_lines([H|T]) :-
  read_line_to_codes(user_input, H), H \= end_of_file, read_lines(T).
read_lines([]).

write_lines([]).
write_lines([H|T]) :-
  writef("%s\n", [H]), write_lines(T).

main :-
  read_lines(X), write_lines(X).
```

(This uses [`writef/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=writef%2F2) for printing.) There are also [`read_stream_to_codes/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_stream_to_codes%2f2) and [`read_stream_to_codes/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_stream_to_codes%2f3), which are not concerned with lines. The following code prints all input from stdin in one go to stdout:

```
main :-
  read_stream_to_codes(user_input, X), writef("%s", [X]).
```

Of course it's also possible to read from a file instead of stdin. For more, see the [`readutil`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282%2c%20%27A.20%27%2c%20swi%28%27%2fdoc%2fManual%2freadutil.html%27%29%29) library.